# Streamlit all buttons are the same

Tags: python, css, streamlit

```
import streamlit as st
import base64

def custom_button(text='button', bgpng=None, height='height: 225px;', width='width: 225px'):
    with open (bgpng, 'rb') as img:
        convert_img = base64.b64encode(img.read()).decode('utf-8')
    background_img = f"background-image: url('data:image/png;base64, {convert_img}');"
    
    st.markdown(f"""
    <style>
    div.stButton > button:first-child {{
        {background_img}
        {height}
        {width}
    }}
    </style>""", unsafe_allow_html=True)
    button = st.button(text)
    return button

button1 = custom_button(text='button', bgpng=r'data\pic1.png')
button2 = custom_button(text='button2', bgpng=r'data\pic2.png')
```

The problem is the following, the last button always determines the properties of the other buttons, in this case the background image of **button2** determines the background image of **button1**. So all buttons have the same background image. How can i solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution.
If the streamlit code is ready, in the browser, right click, inspect , copy the css selector, then we get the unique button css selector. We need to replace this piece of code:
"*div.stButton > button:first-child*"
Should be replaced with: "*copied css selector*"
We have to do it for each button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You create x styles for x buttons so the last style is applyed since it's the same priority.

I don't use python but I guess you could set an id for your buttons and apply your styles to `#{button_id}` (or something like that), or apply inline style like below :

```html
<button style="background-color:orange;">button</button>
<button style="background-color:grey;">button2</button>
```